# Having trouble getting started with bootstrap, can't find files

Tags: jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I'm getting started with Bootstrap but I'm having difficulty in properly displaying the website on account of the fact that I keep getting the error `Not Found: /checkin/css/bootstrap.min.css` and `Not Found: /js/bootstrap.min.js` (**checkin** is the name of my app. Here's the code I'm using that I got from the Bootstrap website:

```
{% load staticfiles %}

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <!-- The above 3 meta tags *must* come first in the head; any other head content must come *after* these tags -->
    <title>Bootstrap 101 Template</title>

    <!-- Bootstrap -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <!-- <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"> -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <!-- HTML5 shim and Respond.js for IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
    <!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/html5shiv/3.7.3/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/bootstrap.min.css' %}">
    <script src="{% static 'jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js' %}"></script>
    <script src="{% static 'js/bootstrap.min.js' %}"></script>

  </head>
  <body>
  <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-static-top">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false">
                <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Balance Web Development</a>
        </div>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
                <li class="dropdown">
                    <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Services<span class="caret"></span></a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                        <li><a href="#">Design</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Development</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Consulting</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>

    <!-- jQuery (necessary for Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins) -->

    <!-- Include all compiled plugins (below), or include individual files as needed -->

</script>
  </body>
</html>
```

I'm not sure what the issue is, I downloaded bootstrap and extracted the `css`, `fonts` and `js` folders to `/checkin/` but the browser can't find them. I downloaded `JQuery` by saving it as jquery.js into the `/checkin/` folder as well.

**EDIT** Some of my project structure:
[image]

[image]

[image]

404 Errors I'm getting in powershell:

[image]

Comment: is your html is also in the checkin folder?

Comment: check your project structure. try this if not getting http://www.tutorialrepublic.com/twitter-bootstrap-tutorial/bootstrap-get-started.php

Comment: You need to share the structure of your project. to get you a solution... This seems like a path related issue. Also **you are loading jquery.js twice**

Comment: Hey thanks for the replies, my html file is in the checkin folder indeed. I updated my post with some pics of folder structure

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maintaining a standard project structure always helps and ease the work for anyone.

For normal web application you can follow this standard practise :

```
root/
   assets/
      lib/-------------------------libraries--------------------
          bootstrap/--------------Libraries can have js/css/images------------
              css/
              js/
              images/  
          jquery/
              js/
          font-awesome/
              css/
              images/
     common/--------------------common section will have application level resources             
          css/
          js/
          img/

 index.html
```

Below is your same file but try linking them properly with your js and css and remove direct online links.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <!-- The above 3 meta tags *must* come first in the head; any other head content must come *after* these tags -->
    <title>Bootstrap 101 Template</title>

    <!-- Bootstrap defualt files -->
    
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    
     <!-- Your Bootstrap and js defualt files (Adjust them) -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    
       
    <!-- your own custom css and js files -->
    
    
    
  </head>
  <body>
  <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-static-top">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false">
                <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Balance Web Development</a>
        </div>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
                <li class="dropdown">
                    <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Services<span class="caret"></span></a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                        <li><a href="#">Design</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Development</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Consulting</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>


  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for this, good news is that the browser is now properly displaying the content. But Django is still giving me `Not Found: /js/bootstrap.min.js` and `Not Found: /bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css` and `Not Found: /jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js`

Comment: Yeah django will create its directory structure... Just need to put your static path in your settings file and load/collect the static files properly...Hey I'm on mobile now..can't give you the exact proper answer right now...but please search about loading static files in django

Comment: I actually looked up static files yesterday when trying to figure this out, so do I need to put just the individual files in `/static/` or should I put the whole directory? eg.`/static/js/bootstrap.min.js`

Comment: @Amon anything inside static folder is collected at backend but it has to be properly linked..put separate folders inside static as js ,css ,images n etc.. Sorry Will update my answer tomorrow till then you have a Try  from tutorials from djangogirls.com

Comment: Okay I updated my file, these are the new lines I added: `<link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/bootstrap.min.css' %}">` and 
    `<script src="{% static 'jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js' %}"></script>` and
    `<script src="{% static 'js/bootstrap.min.js' %}"></script>
    `

Comment: Does that make sense to edit the lines that way? It has solved the `Not Found` error I was getting. However I'm still getting the 404 errors, I've added a screenshot of my powershell window displaying it, thanks

Comment: I got it working, I renamed `bootstrap.min.css` to `bootstrap.min` and for the `jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js` issue I'm not sure, I know I deleted another `jquery` file I had under `/checkin/`. Thanks again, I'd welcome any more feedback on what I did!